# Beginning Windows Mobile 6.1 Development With Python

Tags: python, windows-mobile, mobile-phones

I've wanted to get into Python development for awhile and most of my programming experience has been in .NET and no mobile development.  I recently thought of a useful app to make for my windows mobile phone and thought this could be a great first Python project.

I did a little research online and found PyCe which I think is what I would need to get started on the app?  Can anyone with some experience in this area point me in the right direction?  What to download to get started, what lightweight database I could use, etc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you much with Python\CE but if you want a great db for mobile devices SQLLite will do the job for you. If you do a quick google you'll find there are libraries for connecting to SQLLite with Python too.